# For each loop in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am a beginner in VBA trying to loop through cells from a specified range that is entered into a refEdit on a user form, this range always has 2 columns but could have any number of rows.  The first column is a category and the second column is numerical values.  I want to find the sum of the corresponding values of a specific category.  For example, very time I come across the word "coffee" in a cell I want to take the value in the cell to its right and start summing them to print the value of all coffee in cell C1. How can I get this to work?

Here is what I have been working with:

```
dim cell, myRange as Range
dim c as string
dim r as long
Set myRange = Range(RefEdit1.Text)
c = "coffee"
r = 0
For Each cell In myRange
    If VBA.LCase(cell) = VBA.LCase(c) Then
         r = r + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
next cell
range("C1") = r
```

Comment: Are `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` formulas not suitable for this task?

Answer (score 0):

### SumIf vs Loop

- Loops are usually best avoided due to slowing down the code.
- `SumIf` 'is' not case-sensitive so you are also avoiding the `'LCase`-business'.
- When declaring variables in one line, you have to 'use an `As`' for each variable or it will be declared as `Variant` (`cell`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testSumIf()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim c As String
    Set myRange = Range(RefEdit1.Text)
    c = "coffee"
    Range("C1").Value _
        = Application.SumIf(myRange.Columns(1), c, myRange.Columns(2))
End Sub

Sub testLoop()
    Dim cell As Range, myRange As Range
    Dim c As String
    Dim r As Long
    Set myRange = Range(RefEdit1.Text)
    c = VBA.LCase("coffee")
    For Each cell In myRange.Cells
        If VBA.LCase(cell.Value) = c Then
             r = r + cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cell
    Range("C1").Value = r
End Sub
```